# How to exclude a field in hibernate schema autogeneration from @MappedSuperclass?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How can I tell `hibernate` to ignore a field during schema auto generation?
In this special case: the field is inherited from a parent abstract class, so I cannot just comment it out!

I tried using `@Transient`, but the field is still autogenerated in the schema.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    private String someField;
    //getter+setter
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {
     @Transient //I want to ignore this field during hibernate.ddl.auto
     @Override
     public String getSomeField() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Transient annotation in the super class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Transient
    private String someField;
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {
}
```

Comment: That's exactly not what I want, because it would affect all implementations. I only want to change it in one specific.

Comment: That's not possible. To achieve something similar you could create a hierarchy of MappedSuperclasses one with and one without that field